# can I run suger CRM on local as free / Trial User?

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm

I am freelance developer . I don't own company . Can i set up sugar crm on local machine . I am seeing they have stopped community edition to download . I also tried to contact sales but they are not responding . Only online trial option available for 7 days . Is it only solution ?

Comment: https://www.sugarcrm.com/pricing/

Comment: So now set up cannot be download more like before for free

Comment: yep, you'll need to setup the trial option

Answer (score 1):

SugarCRM does not give to code-level access to any of there version after 6 for free.

The community edition is now backed by suitecrm and I would recommend using it. It uses the core SugarCRM CE.

Also, SugarCRM after community edition is majorly changed with new backbone js based sidecar framework they have developed themselves.